# Chromium gets black after long time, xubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, chromium, xubuntu

I have searched and tried almost everything. I have problems with my web app. It needs to be open for long time. I have launcher, that runs when I turn on pc.

`chromium-browser --kiosk "http://localhost/" --incognito --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0 --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream %U`

But after serval hours chrome gets black (black screen) I see mouse pointer, I can minimize it, open terminal, see desktop but the chrome is black and I cant use my app.

Is it something with memory? In thouse hours there is flash banner in loop, maybe that affects? When it runs for some 1 or 3 hours it all ok, I come tap on banner it disapers and I can use my app, but when I leave it for night in morning it gets black, but I need it to run for days with not touched and still working.

Someone have some idea?